# How to access Google Hangouts chat on Mobile Safari?

Tags: iphone, google-hangouts

I don't want to download the Google Hangouts app on my phone. Is there a way to access Google Hangouts chat using a mobile browser such as mobile Safari?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to `gmail.com` in mobile Safari.
2. Hold the refresh button, and choose **Request Desktop Site**.

   It will look exactly the same, but it actually did something.
3. Go up to the URL and delete everything after `https://mail.google.com/`.

The chat windows will be really small and barely usable, but you can at least read messages and probably send them too.

---

If you do things in a different order or try to use the button at the bottom of the screen to toggle between `standard` and `basic HTML`, you'll either end up going back to the mobile site, or you'll end up with the following error:

> You have been redirected to the basic HTML version because this browser is not supported. To use standard view please upgrade to a supported browser.

Ignore that message and try opening up a new tab and trying that same process above.